# shinyAPP: change the value of a reactive dataset

Tags: r, shiny-server, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I want to programm a shiny app for my daughter to lern vocabularies.

The dataset is a data.frame with four columns: Unit, Part, German, Engilsh

My daughter should select first the Unit, then the Part. This works fine and gives an interactive dataframe. I call it `seldf`, in the reactive code it is `seldf()`.

After that the shinyapp selects randomly from this interactive dataframe one line and asks: Whats the Englisch word for the German expression?

This should be typed in a `inputText` field by my daughter. Then she has to click on the **Proove**-button to `prove` if her input is correct. Also this works fine!

To continue learning, there is another actionbutton - **Next word** - to get the next randomly choosen German expression.

And here are my problems:

If my daughter was right, the row with the German expression translated correctly should be removed from `seldf()`. Most likely I want to "remove" the line by filtering. That means I want to add a flag into the dataframe. This is needed for the filter expression filters the new `seldf()` correctly
If my daughter was wrong, `seldf()` remains unchanged.

How can I do this within my code?

You'll find my code here:

https://github.com/StatistikVolker/Vokabeln

Stay healthy!

Volker

Comment: As per the [site guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), sample code should be included in the post itself, and should be [minimal, complete and representative](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than randomly choosing a new word each time your daughter clicks "Next button", I think it will be slightly easier to sort the `seldf` (non-reactive) dataframe into a random order when the app loads.  The Proove button's `observeEvent` handler checks to see if she's answered correctly, displays an appropriate message, and updates the non-reactive `seldf` if appropriate.  The `seldf()` reactive the simply returns the first row of the filtered (non-reactive) dataframe each time she clicks next.

Something like this (untested) code:

```
# Sort the input dataframe into random order (and add an "answered" flag)
inputDF <- inputDF %>% 
             mutate(
               Random=runif(nrow(.), 
               CorrectlyAnswered=FALSE
             ) %>% 
             arrange(Random)

# Provide the current question and answer
seldf <- reactive ({
  # Ensure response after a correct answer
  input$proove
  inputDF %>% filter(!AnsweredCorrectly) %>% head(1)
})

# Handle Proove button clicks
observeEvent(input$proove, {
  req(seldf(), input$answerText)

  if (seldf()$English[1] == input$answerText) {
    inputDF <- inputDF %>% 
                 mutate(
                   CorrectlyAnswered=ifelse(
                                       English == input$answerText, 
                                       TRUE, 
                                       CorrectlyAnswered
                                     )
                   )
    # Display success message
  } else {
    # Display failure message
  }
})
```

***Update***

Here's a MWE based on the `mtcars` dataset to show how a `reactive` can be used to dynamically filter a static base dataframe.  The UI uses two `selectInput`s to create a `reactive` based on user-defined filtering of the `mtcars` dataset.  The `reactive` is then used to display a plot and data listing.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Note the use of "- Show all -"="" to allow a "no filter" option
  selectInput(
    inputId="cylSelect", 
    label="Filter by number of cylinders", 
    choices=c("- Show all -"="", sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))),
    multiple=TRUE
  ),
  selectInput(
    inputId="carbSelect", 
    label="Filter by number of carburetor barrels", 
    choices=c("- Show all -"="", sort(unique(mtcars$carb))),
    multiple=TRUE
  ),
  plotOutput("plot"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   filteredCars <- reactive({
      df <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("Model")
      if (!is.null(input$cylSelect)) {
        df <- df %>% filter(cyl %in% input$cylSelect)
      }
      if (!is.null(input$carbSelect)) {
        df <- df %>% filter(cyl %in% input$carbSelect)
      }
      df
   })
   
   output$plot <- renderPlot({
     filteredCars() %>% 
       ggplot() + 
         geom_point(aes(x=mpg, y=disp, colour=as.factor(gear)))
   })
   
   output$table <- renderTable({ filteredCars() })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you need to trigger an update to the `reactive` in response to a button click, just reference the button in the `reactive` as I did in my original post.  That's sufficient to trigger an update.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. Indeed it is a good idea th sort the data randomly before my daugther starts learning. But this is only a working examle for another problem, where I really need to write data into a reactive dataframe. Therfor two bounties for your solution, but the questions remains open and unaswerd :-)

Comment: Can you expand on your comment about writing to a "reactive dataframe"?  I believe this is the effect of my code: there is a (non-reactive) dataframe `inputDF` that is manipulated in the event handler for the action button `input$proove`.  Then, a reference to the *same* input button within the reactive ensures that it is updated in response to changes to the underlying (non-reactive) dataframe.  Since, as you imply, it is not possible to write to a reactive, this approach provides the functionality you need.

Comment: Youre right. ```inputDF``` in your example is a nonreactive Dataframe. And then it is possible to manipulate it.
My problem is, hat my ```inputDF``` is filtered by two ```checkboxGroupInput```s within the shinyAPP first and then I randomly select a vocabulary.
If I now write back to the ```inputDF``` the selection process is not done again (because nothing changed in the ```checkboxGroupInput```s).
I think 2 ways may solve my problem: (1) I write to the reactive dataset defined as mentioned above or (2) the filterig process of the ```inputDF``` ist done everytime again.

Comment: Yes.  Either will work.  And, unless the base dataframe is very large, I don't think there will be much difference in performance.My solution (your option 1) generalises very easily: just reference the relevant inputs in the reactive and adapt the filtering appropriately.

Comment: OK and thank you, but now I'm lost: How to "reference the relevant inputs in the reactive and adapt the filtering appropriately"?

Comment: Thank you for your Update and sorry for my late answer. I was offline due to a family weekend. But I can't solve my problem with it. I do not understand how to save data into the ```mtcars``` dataset and use this for refilter the dataset in the next step.
See my answer to y post with Code example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my not-working try to save back data to the original dataframe, based on the Update of the 1 answer from @Limey.
Problem is, output$table is not updated and in a second run still all datarows of `mtcars` are in my analysis.
How to add a variable to `mtcars` to filter for further analysis?

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Note the use of "- Show all -"="" to allow a "no filter" option
  # Select mtcars by cylinders
  selectInput(
    inputId="cylSelect", 
    label="Filter by number of cylinders", 
    choices=c("- Show all -"="", sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))),
    multiple=TRUE
  ),
  # Action Button to Save analysed Data
  actionButton("save","Save"),
  # show datatable
  tableOutput("table"),
  tableOutput("filtab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Define extra variable into the mtcars dataset.
  inputDF <- mtcars %>% 
    rownames_to_column("Model") %>%
    mutate(analysed=FALSE)
  
  # Filter out cars by cylinder
  filteredCars <- reactive({
    df <- inputDF  %>% filter(analysed == FALSE)
    if (!is.null(input$cylSelect)) {
      df <- df %>% 
        filter(cyl %in% input$cylSelect)
    }
    df
  })

  
  # Save "analysed" cars based on reactive choosen cylinders back to dataset mt cars for next step in Analysis.
  # -- don't work! --
  observeEvent(input$Save,{
    if (!is.null(input$cylSelect)) {
      mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
        mutate(analysed = ifelse(cyl %in% input$cylSelect,TRUE,analysed)) 
    }
  })
  
  # Show updated mtcars
  # -- don't work! --
  output$table <- renderTable({ mtcars%>% rownames_to_column("Model") })

  # Show Filtered Table
  output$filtab <- renderTable({ filteredCars() })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with OP's answer above.

First, there's a scoping problem in `observeEvent(input$Save`.  Event observers are functions.  So `mtcars <- mtcars ...` creates a *local* (modified) copy of the global `mtcars` object, which is then discarded when the event observer terminates.  The `mtcars` referenced in `output$table <- renderTable` is the unchanged global object.  One symptom of this is that the table displayed by `output$table` does not contain the `analysed` column.

Second, the id of the action button is `save`, not `Save`.  `Dave` is its label.  So the event observer is never triggered anyway.  A good technique to confirm that an event observer (or other ractive) is being triggered when you expect it to be triggered is simply to put a `print` statement inside the reactive.

To get the functionality the OP requires, we need to reverse the logic of my original suggestion.  We need to retain the rows which are *not* currently selected when the `save` button is clicked.  This suggests changing the name (id) of the button to `analyse` ("Analyse") would make sense.

Secondly, to ensure that the non-reactive filtered dataset is updated only when the save button is clicked (and not when the selction in the `selectCyl` select input is updated, we need to `isolate` the reference to `input$selectCyl`.

Finally, to overcome the scoping issue described above, we need to use the global assignment operator `<<-` (or more generally, `assign`) in the event observer.

In the code below, `analysedCars` updates only when the `Analyse` button is clicked.  `filteredCars` updates as soon as the selection in `selectCyl` changes.

Note that `filteredCars` allows rows to be "unanalysed": that is rows will be added back in to the filtered dataset in response to changes to the `selectCyl` select input.  This does not happen with `analysedCars`.  This appears to the the OP's intent.

Until rows are unanalysed, the only difference between the behaviours of `filteredCars` and `analysedCars` is the timing of the updates.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # Note the use of "- Show all -"="" to allow a "no filter" option
  # Select mtcars by cylinders
  selectInput(
    inputId="cylSelect", 
    label="Filter by number of cylinders", 
    choices=c("- Show all -"="", sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))),
    multiple=TRUE
  ),
  # Action Button to Save analysed Data
  actionButton("analyse","Analyse"),
  # show datatable
  tableOutput("table"),
  tableOutput("filtab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #Define extra variable into the mtcars dataset.
  inputDF <- mtcars %>% 
    rownames_to_column("Model") %>%
    mutate(analysed=FALSE)
  # Take a copy for delayed updates
  analysedCars <- inputDF
  
  filteredCars <- reactive({
    df <- inputDF  %>% filter(analysed == FALSE)
    if (!is.null(input$cylSelect)) {
      df <- df %>% 
        filter(!(cyl %in% input$cylSelect))
    }
    df
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$analyse,{
    isolate({
      analysedCars <<- analysedCars %>% 
        mutate(analysed = cyl %in% input$cylSelect) %>% 
        filter(!analysed)
    })
    analysedCars
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({ 
    input$analyse
    analysedCars
  })
  
  output$filtab <- renderTable({ filteredCars() })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```