# I want to link multiple Input UIs like a filter with ShinyApp

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Currently developing ShinyApp.
I want to narrow down the input data from multiple Input UIs.

The sample file is below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J2A3Z-wjg1RjUfC6ion3CyHWatmdg9vO/view?usp=sharing

The sample code is below.

```
ui.r

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

dataset <- diamonds
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  fluidRow(

    column(3,
           fileInput('file', 'Choose CSV File', 
                       accept=c(
                         "text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")
                       ),
    ),
    
    column(3,
           pickerInput('PI1',
                       'Choose1',
                       choices=c(""),
                       multiple  =  TRUE
           ),
    ),
    
    column(3,
           sliderInput('SI',
                       'SliderChoose', 
                       min=0, max=100, value=c(40, 80))
    ),
    
    column(3,
           pickerInput('PI2',
                       'Choose2',
                       choices=c(""),
                       multiple  =  TRUE
     ),
    ),
  ),
  dataTableOutput("datatable")
  ))
```

```
server.r

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)

function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  observeEvent(input$file, {

    csvfile = read.csv(input$file$datapath)

    PI1_Choice <- as.vector(unique(csvfile$filter1))
    updatePickerInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "PI1",
      choices = PI1_Choice
    )
    
    max_value <- max(as.numeric((csvfile$filter2)))
    min_value <- min(as.numeric((csvfile$filter2)))
    updateSliderInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "SI",
      max = max_value,
      min = min_value,
      value = c(min,max)
    )
    
    PI2_Choice <- as.vector(unique(csvfile$filter3))
    updatePickerInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "PI2",
      choices = PI2_Choice
    )
    
    output$datatable = renderDataTable(csvfile)

  })

}
```

When you load the sample file, a data table of all the data will be generated.
[image]
I want to narrow down the displayed data table by selecting Choose1, SliderChoose, and Choose2.

What kind of processing should I do?
If anyone knows, please let me know.

Comment: Create a `reactive` based on the (static) contents of the csvfile and the reactive values returned by `Choose1`, `Choose2` and `SliderChoose`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [shinyAPP: change the value of a reactive dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66816990/shinyapp-change-the-value-of-a-reactive-dataset)